# Prevent Email Duplicates

Tags: php, sql

I have been trying to prevent any user from registering an email that is already registered in the database. I couldn't. Maybe it's because I have to check three tables at the same time. I tried but failed. I hope you are able to help me.

```
        //Check whether Email exists or not
        $check="SELECT * FROM admins, engineers, users WHERE admins.Email='$email' OR engineers.Email='$email' OR users.Email='$email'";
        $results=mysql_query($check);



        //Confirm that the Email doesn't exist
        if(mysql_num_rows($results) == 0)
        { $check='true'; }



        //Error message to the user that the Email already exists.
        else
        {
            header("location: register.php?email=false"); 
        }



        //Register the data
        if($check=='true')
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO admins (Admin, Password, Email, Phone, Date, Time) VALUES ('$username', '$password','$email', '$phone', '$date', '$time')");
            header("location: login.php?register=success");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have emails in 3 different tables? Make one table that contains the information that's common to all types of users, and then use foreign keys in the other tables.

Comment: and don't use mysql_query as it is deprecated. and sanitize $email before passing it into your sql

Comment: make your email friend an unique field .

Comment: and always call exit after using header()...Like so: `header(whatever);exit;`

Comment: What is the failure that you are observing?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not an expert my friend.

Comment: @HassanAhmed I will try setting it as a unique field but I want the error message to be displayed to the user.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal I didn't understand what you meant in the first comment, I'm not an expert. And you said that I should call exit after using header. What effect will that have?

Comment: @B98 The failure is that it registers the email in the database when it already exists.

Comment: @Nizar setting the email as a unique will allow you to handle errors in case of duplicates and then parse that error to the user the way you want .

Comment: _and don't use mysql_query as it is deprecated_ ==> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php the red notice.

_and sanitize $email before passing it into your sql_ ==> $email is something that a user enters in a webform right? if you take that from the let's say $_POST var and pass it to your database directly, a user can inject harmful code. ==> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters
would you should at least always do with such vars is mysql_real_escape_string($email).

Comment: @HassanAhmed Thanks for your tip. I will try it.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal wow such a useful information. I learned a lot from you. I wish you can direct me to something that teaches me to `code like a pro`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` rather than a cross-product.

```
SELECT 1 FROM admins WHERE email = '$email'
UNION
SELECT 1 FROM engineers WHERE email = '$email'
UNION
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

The cross-product will only work if it finds matches in all the tables, not just one of them.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Did it get an error? What happens if you run the query by hand?

Comment: I don't see how this could fail. Maybe there are extra characters in `$email`, try using `var_dump($check);` to see the whole query.

Comment: oh, I was able to identify the problem now. The problem was that I didn't add `exit();` after every `header(...)`. Which is why even after finding a duplicate in the database, It still stores it. After adding `exit();` after every header, the problem was solved. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I thought that was the point of `if($check == 'true')`. BTW, don't use strings for true/false, PHP has a boolean type with constants `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life easier by storing all emails in one table. You can use a column named for example 'type' which would then be admin, user or engineer. This makes your lookups much easier instead of having to look through multiple tables.

Comment: You're right. That will make it easier. But I wanted to do it the faster way. Also, I want to learn more, I can't stay a noob forever. Anyway, I will try your suggestion in case I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: One thing that seperates the "noobs" from the "pros" is proper database normalization. having 3 table with very equal information that just differs in there type and content is the worst thing to do.

Comment: instead of having three tables (admins,engineers,users) for an entity "user" you should have ONE table

Comment: @AlexOdenthal The funny thing is, all three tables have the same exact columns except for `Engineers` it has one extra column. I guess that means I should reconstruct my tables.

Comment: yes you should. make one new table with the structure of "engineers". put all users inside and just fill the "special column for engineers" and leave it empty for the rest of the users